Let $T$ be a linear map from $V$ to to $V$, such that $\Vert {T(v)}\Vert \leq \Vert{v} \Vert$ for all $v\in V$. Prove $T -\sqrt{2} I$ is injective
I chose to attempt a proof by contrapositive
If $T -\sqrt{2}I$ is  not injective, then for some $v \in V$, $\Vert{Tv}\Vert > \Vert{v}\Vert$.
As $T -\sqrt{2}I$ is not injective, for some $v,u; v \neq u$; $T(v-u) = \sqrt2({v-u})$
Thus $\Vert{T(v-u)}\Vert \geq \Vert {v-u}\Vert$
We now want to assure ourselves that this isn't always an equality.
To do so, we look at the definition:
$
\sqrt{\langle T(v - u), T(v - u) \rangle} \geq \sqrt{\langle v - u, v - u \rangle}$.
This gives us
$\langle T(v - u), T(v - u) \rangle \geq \langle v - u, v - u \rangle.$
now what

Consider $(T-\sqrt{2}I)v = 0$. Then $Tv = \sqrt{2}v$. Putting this in the inequality we will get $\Vert \sqrt{2}v \Vert \leq \Vert v \Vert \implies \Vert v \Vert \leq 0 \implies v = 0$. So null space of $(T-\sqrt{2}I)v = 0$ is only ${0}$ which shows that it is injective.

The inequality $||T(v - u)|| \geq ||v - u||$ that you wrote is actually strict. In fact, $$||T(v - u)|| = ||\sqrt{2}(v - u)|| = \sqrt{2}||v - u|| > ||v - u||.$$

isn't multiplicative linearity one of the defining features of the norm?

Yes. $||cv|| = |c| \cdot ||v||$. This property is called absolute homogeneity.

So how did the inequality become strict ?

It became strict because $\sqrt{2} > 1$ and $||v - u|| \neq 0$.

ah yeah, got it. Thanks!
